# connect to server through GUI

Tags: networking, server, ssh, software-recommendation

I am on Ubuntu Mate 22.04, though the I use the connect to server option in a variety of Desktop Environments. It works well most of the time, but right now, I would like to connect with a server that needs the `-oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa` option for ssh.

alternatively a method that would allow me to interact with the ssh server via the window manager would also be acceptable. There is no provision for this in the "Connect to server" option, and trying to pass the argument though the available inputs doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: With key authentication you need no password, so it should be straightforward to connect to the server. You can put the whole command line into a shellscript or alias.